# Ignorar arquivos da pasta obj\Debug

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, team-foundation-server

Estou com um problema, todas as vezes que vou fazer check in o visual studio relaciona esses arquivos :

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei um arquivo (.tfignore) para tentar ignora-los mas não funcionou :

```
\packages
\obj
\bin
\_design\.sass-cache
\_design\scss
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Alguém imagina alguma solução?

Comment: Qual a versão do TFS?

Comment: Estou utilizando o VS2017.

Comment: E qual a versão do TFS? É a 2017?

Comment: Versão 2017, hospedagem online.